# JDBC finding the source of unclosed connections?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, connection

I am having issues where somewhere in my project several connections to mysql are not being closed, causing my application to become very slow after a couple of days,essentially forcing me to restart my application server.

To find the source of this issue i created a map where the key was the class and method name of what was making the connection, and as the value a count that would get incremented and decremented every time that method made/closed a connection, i thought this would let me see which method making a connection to the database was leaving a lot of connections open, this turned out to be inaccurate.

What would you suggest i do to find the source of the unclosed connection other than manually going through the code to find the source?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer but a suggestion, why don't you create a pool of connections and select a connection from it, it would be cleaner than opening and closing connections.

Comment: Please provide more details on how are you creating the connection. Are the connections being created from single component has its own code of  opening/closing connections? Are you using some framework (high probably not). You may want to provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (not straight forward) would to use BTrace. You would create scripts intercepting the `java.sql.connection` code

https://kenai.com/projects/btrace

The requirement would be however:

1. Either you would be using Oracle JDK6+
2. Or running application with Sun JDK5 on Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `aspectj` to add tracing/logging/interceptors at various methods (`DriverManager.getConnection` etc.).

However I suggest centralizing your connection management, and paying attention to handle exceptions correctly (even this can be centralized).

Answer (score 0):

Use a connection pool that can trap abandoned connections, such as Apache DNCP.